# Area of a generic polygon inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

Given that a generic $n$-gon ($n\geq3$) is inscribed in a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we know the lengths of all its edges $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$. Are there formulae to calculate its area (under Euclidean metric)?

For $n=3$, let $p=\frac{\sum_{i\in [n]} a_i}{2}$, we have the Heron's formula:
$$A=\sqrt{p(p-a_1)(p-a_2)(p-a_3)}$$
which is the special case of the following $n=4$ formula ($a_4=0$):
$$ A=\sqrt{(p-a_1)(p-a_2)(p-a_3)(p-a_4)}.$$
Are there any known result for $n\geq 5$?

If not, any proof that certain formulae don't exist?

Comment: Is the $n$-gon convex? If it intersects itself, what precisely do you mean by the area?

Comment: See Theorem 1 in [D. P. Robbins, *Areas of polygons inscribed in a circle*, Discrete & Computational Geometry, 12(2), 223--236](http://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02574377). I suspect there are many more articles about this now. But I don't think there is an explicit formula (I would guess it is an equation that cannot be solved in radicals for sufficiently high $n$).